# Make a pop up comment window, similar to reddit html/css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to recreate Reddit as a project to learn html/css/JS. I am having a hard time figuring out how to recreate the comment button and its following effect. For example, when a user clicks [image: reddit comment]

it loads another window, within the current window. You can click to the side to exit the window and go back to where you were on the page. Similar to below.

[image: reddit comment]

I have tried researching it, but I can't find the technical term for this effect so am having a hard time locating how to do it.

Thank you for any information you can provide.

Comment: The technical term is a modal. If you want to learn about modals, click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

Comment: @JWingert the term to search is modal window as mentioned above. The thing to notice here though is that as the modal window pops up it has no content. The information that will populate it comes from new requests to the server. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Fantastic, thank you both so much. That's exactly what I was looking for.